# Is it possible to carry local RSA keys to remote computer (live) and use securely?

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

Is it possible to store an SSH-id in some sort of session (like expect or ssh) that is running on the local machine, swing into a remote box, and execute a shell command in the remote box as if the SSH-id is on that remote box, even though it is actually in-memory in the live session on the local box?

Basically, is it possible to proxy the shell on a remote, run shell commands on the remote, with the local ssh daemon in-the-loop?

Comment: Have you ever used the SSH Agent (`ssh-agent`), and if so, have you tried enabling agent forwarding?

Comment: @Kusalananda working through that now

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks